# Node.js cluster - optimal number of workers

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, node-cluster

I have 4 cores and ran this code according to [this example](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster) :

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

var id = 0;
if (cluster.isWorker) {
    id = cluster.worker.id;
}

var iterations = 1000000000;
console.time('Function #' + id);
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    var test = 0;
}
console.timeEnd('Function #' + id);

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Fork workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
}
```

With 4 fork (the code above), I got :

> Function #0: 1698.801ms
>
> Function #1: 3282.679ms
>
> Function #4: 3290.384ms
>
> Function #3: 3425.090ms
>
> Function #2: 3424.922ms

With 3 fork, I got :

> Function #0: 1695.155ms
>
> Function #2: 1822.867ms
>
> Function #3: 2444.156ms
>
> Function #1: 2606.680ms

With 2 fork, I got :

> Function #0: 1684.929ms
>
> Function #1: 1682.897ms
>
> Function #2: 1686.123ms

I don't understand these results. Isn't **1 fork/core** the **optimal** number ? Here I see that 4 fork is not better than 2 fork.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that your hardware actually only has 2 *physical* cores. However, because of [hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) (HT), the OS will say that there are 4 (logical) cores present.

The workers in your code keep a (physical) core entirely occupied, which is something that HT can't deal with very well, so the performance when keeping all 4 logical cores busy will be worse than when you keep only the 2 physical cores busy.

My hardware (quad core, so 4 physical and 8 logical cores) shows the same pattern:

- 8 workers:

  ```
  Function #5: 926ms
  Function #3: 916ms
  Function #1: 928ms
  Function #4: 895ms
  Function #7: 934ms
  Function #6: 905ms
  Function #8: 928ms
  Function #2: 928ms
  ```
- 4 workers:

  ```
  Function #3: 467ms
  Function #2: 467ms
  Function #1: 473ms
  Function #4: 472ms
  ```

That said, the rule of thumb of making the number of workers equivalent to the number of logical cores in your hardware still makes sense if your workers are I/O bound (which most Node apps are).

If you really want to perform heavy, blocking, calculations, count one *physical* core per worker.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Then for Node.js the other half of the cores are only used for the asynchronous code ? Does it requires cluster or does it means that Node.js uses only one execution thread but **also** others parallels threads (~ cores ?) for the asynchronous code ? Also, as I'm developping a game, it's mainly CPU bound. But I saw in a github work some `setTimeout(updateClients, 0);` in the mainloop because "asynchronous updates increase performance". Are they right ?

Comment: Node itself doesn't schedule anything, that's up to the OS (and also the CPU itself). If you have CPU-bound code, `cluster` can help you because it'll allow you to run the CPU-heavy code in a separate process, that the OS can schedule onto a different code as the "main" part of the app. Using the `setTimeout()` trick is useful if you're mixing I/O-bound and CPU-bound core together in the same process.